# Custom row in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-grid

I have a grid that shows a few columns and two buttons that are created via the `command` option, like this:

```
columns: [
    {"field": "titulo", "title": "Titulo"},
    {"field": "start", "title": "Fecha inicio"},
    {"field": "end", "title": "Fecha fin"},
    {"field": "progreso", "title": "Progreso"},
    {"field": "prioridad", "title": "Prioridad"},
    {"field": "estado", "title": "Estado"},
    { command: [
        { text: "Ver", click: ver_detalles, className: "tiny button" },
        { text: "Borrar", click: borrar_incidencia, className: "tiny button" },
    ], title: "Acciones" }
],
```

Now I'd like to use my own `rowTemplate`, but I'm not sure how to make Kendo place the buttons in my custom row.

Is there a way for doing that or I'll have to create my own buttons?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question you want to put new `button` in command or you want to add button in `rowTemplate` ?

Comment: @Jaimin I want to make KendoUI add the ```command``` buttons to my  ```rowTemplate```

Comment: I think you use `clientTemplate` for customize your `Command button`.` rowTemplate` looking not good option.